# How to convert a date into day of the week in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with date in a python dataframe. How to convert this into a week day.

I tried this:

```
train_df['DayofWeek'] = train_df['Date_variable'].weekday()
```

This is not working. If possible, please help.

Also, I want to baseline a day and want to count the days. How to do that? For example, lets say 10th september would be my day 1, 11th september would be my day 2 and so on and store it as a separate variable.

How this can be achieved.

Comment: Could you share the head of your data frame? This may help understand why it is not working.

Comment: Have you used the .dt accessor? `train_df.Date_variable.dt.weekday` ?

Comment: @JonClements - This has worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Agarp - I beleive, it could be because i have not added the .dt accessor mentioned by Jon Clements. Thanks for taking time to help me out